# Magento 2 How can I add loyalty / reward points for customers?

Tags: magento2, reward-points

In Magento 2 Enterprise edition how can i add the reward point for a customer?

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stores.dotsquares.com/php/magento2/refer-friend-and-reward-point-in-magento2.html Can this be useful?

Answer (score 3):

For example we want to assign the reward points when customer save event (customer_save_after_data_object) observer is called then it will be like this

```
namespace Aizar\CustomerStatus\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Reward\Model\Reward;
use Magento\Reward\Model\Reward\HistoryFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Reward\Model\RewardFactory;

class CustomerSaveObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * Reward factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Reward\Model\RewardFactory
     */
    protected $_rewardFactory;


    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;


    public function __construct(RewardFactory $rewardFactory,
                                StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                                ManagerInterface $messageManager)
    {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_rewardFactory = $rewardFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $reward \Magento\Reward\Model\Reward */
        $newCustomerData = $observer->getCustomerDataObject();
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
        $reward = $this->_rewardFactory->create()->setCustomer($newCustomerData)
                       ->setCustomerId($newCustomerData->getId())
                       ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                       ->loadByCustomer()
                       ->setAction(\Magento\Reward\Model\Reward::REWARD_ACTION_ADMIN)
                    ->setComment(__('Additional Information Reward'))
                    ->updateRewardPoints();
     $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(__('You have got %1 reward pints', $reward->getPointsDelta()));

    }

}
```

I hope it will help someone. Please vote up my answer if it will help you. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/Vendor/CustomReward/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Save.php**

```
    <?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\CustomReward\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create;

use Exception;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote;
use Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\PaymentException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total;
use Magento\Reward\Model\Reward;
use Magento\Reward\Model\Reward\History;
use Magento\Reward\Model\RewardFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
class Save extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save
{
    /**
     * @var Action\Context
     */
    private $context;
    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    private $productHelper;
    /**
     * @var Quote
     */
    private $quoteBackendSession;
    /**
     * @var History
     */
    private $rewardHistory;
    /**
     * @var Reward
     */
    private $rewardFactory;
    /**
     * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    private $priceCurrency;

    /**
     * Saving quote and create order
     *
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     * @param History $rewardHistory
     * @param RewardFactory $rewardFactory
     * @param Quote $quoteBackendSession
     * @param Product $productHelper
     * @param Escaper $escaper
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function __construct(Action\Context $context, PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency , History $rewardHistory, RewardFactory $rewardFactory, Quote $quoteBackendSession, Product $productHelper, Escaper $escaper, PageFactory $resultPageFactory, ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $productHelper, $escaper, $resultPageFactory, $resultForwardFactory);
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->productHelper = $productHelper;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        $this->quoteBackendSession = $quoteBackendSession;
        $this->rewardHistory = $rewardHistory;
        $this->rewardFactory = $rewardFactory;
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $path = 'sales/*/';
        $pathParams = [];

        try {
            // check if the creation of a new customer is allowed
            if (!$this->_authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Customer::manage')
                && !$this->_getSession()->getCustomerId()
                && !$this->_getSession()->getQuote()->getCustomerIsGuest()
            ) {
                return $this->resultForwardFactory->create()->forward('denied');
            }
            if ($this->quoteBackendSession->getQuote()->getUseRewardPoints() == true){
                $quote = $this->quoteBackendSession->getQuote();
                $customer = $quote->getCustomer();
                $reward = $this->rewardFactory->create()->setCustomer($customer);
                $reward->setWebsiteId($quote->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                $reward->loadByCustomer();
                $getPointBalance = $reward->getPointsBalance();
            }
            $payment = $this->getRequest()->getParam('payment');
            if ($this->quoteBackendSession->getQuote()->getUseRewardPoints() == false) {
                unset($payment['custom_reward']);
            }else{
                $customReward = $payment['custom_reward'];
            }
            if ($this->quoteBackendSession->getQuote()->getUseRewardPoints() == false) {
                $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->getQuote()->setCustomerId($this->_getSession()->getCustomerId());
            } elseif($customReward > $getPointBalance) {
                throw new InputException(__("No Enough Reward points"));
            }else{
                $customReward = $payment['custom_reward'];
                $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->getQuote()->setCustomerId($this->_getSession()->getCustomerId());
                $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->getQuote()->setData('reward_points_balance', $customReward);
                $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->getQuote()->setData('base_reward_currency_amount', $customReward);
                $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->getQuote()->setData('reward_currency_amount', $customReward);
                $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->getQuote()->setData('payment_by_reward_points', $customReward);
                $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->getQuote()->setData('points_used', $customReward);
                $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
                $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->getQuote()->save();
            }
            $this->_processActionData('save');
            $paymentData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment');
            if ($paymentData) {
                $paymentData['checks'] = [
                    AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_INTERNAL,
                    AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY,
                    AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_FOR_CURRENCY,
                    AbstractMethod::CHECK_ORDER_TOTAL_MIN_MAX,
                    AbstractMethod::CHECK_ZERO_TOTAL,
                ];
                $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->setPaymentData($paymentData);
                $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->getQuote()->getPayment()->addData($paymentData);
            }
            if ($this->quoteBackendSession->getQuote()->getUseRewardPoints() == false) {
                $order = $this->_getOrderCreateModel()
                    ->setIsValidate(true)
                    ->importPostData($this->getRequest()->getPost('order'))
                    ->createOrder();
            }else{
                $order = $this->_getOrderCreateModel()
                    ->setIsValidate(true)
                    ->importPostData($this->getRequest()->getPost('order'))
                    ->createOrder();
                $order->setRewardPointsBalance($customReward);
                $order->setBaseRewardCurrencyAmount($customReward);
                $order->setRewardCurrencyAmount($customReward);
                $order->setPaymentByRewardPoints($customReward);
                $order->setPointsUsed($customReward);
                $order->save();
            }
            $this->rewardHistoryOrder($this->quoteBackendSession->getQuote(), $order);

            $this->_getSession()->clearStorage();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You created the order.'));
            if ($this->_authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Sales::actions_view')) {
                $pathParams = ['order_id' => $order->getId()];
                $path = 'sales/order/view';
            } else {
                $path = 'sales/order/index';
            }
        } catch (PaymentException $e) {
            $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->saveQuote();
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            if (!empty($message)) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($message);
            }
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            // customer can be created before place order flow is completed and should be stored in current session
            $this->_getSession()->setCustomerId((int)$this->_getSession()->getQuote()->getCustomerId());
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            if (!empty($message)) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($message);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Order saving error: %1', $e->getMessage()));
        }

        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath($path, $pathParams);
    }

    public function rewardHistoryOrder($quote, $order){
        $customer = $quote->getCustomer();
        $reward = $quote->getRewardInstance();
        if (!$reward || !$reward->getId()) {
            $reward = $this->rewardFactory->create()->setCustomer($customer);
            $reward->setWebsiteId($quote->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
            $reward->loadByCustomer();
            $reward->setUsed($quote->getPointBalance());
            $reward->getPointBalance();
        }
        $setDeltaPoints = (-1 * $quote->getRewardPointsBalance());
        $pointLeft = $reward->getPointsBalance();
        $reward->setPointsBalance($pointLeft);
        $reward->setPointsDelta($setDeltaPoints)->setIsCappedReward(true)->updateRewardPoints();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/CustomReward/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save"
                type="Vendor\CustomReward\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/CustomReward/view/adminhtml/templates/sales/order/create/payment.phtml**

canUseRewardPoints()) :?>

```
<div class="admin__field admin__field-option">
    <input id="p_method_use_reward_points"
           class="admin__control-checkbox"
           value="1"
           name="payment[use_reward_points]"
           type="checkbox"
           <?php if ($block->useRewardPoints() ) :?>checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> />
    <label class="admin__field-label" for="p_method_use_reward_points">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getUseLabel(), ['span']); ?>
    </label>
    <script>
        require(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function($) {
            var toggleUseRewardPoints = function () {
                var checked = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
                var data = {};
                data['payment[use_reward_points]'] = checked;
                order.loadArea(['totals', 'billing_method'], true, data);
            };
            var refundRewardPointsEnable = $('#p_method_use_reward_points');
            refundRewardPointsEnable.change(toggleUseRewardPoints);
        });
    </script>
</div>
<?php if ($block->canUseRewardPoints()) :?>
    <?php if ($block->useRewardPoints() ) :?>
    <div class="test">
        <input type="text" class="admin__control-text required-entry _required" name="payment[custom_reward]" id="custom_reward_set">
        <button id="submit_reward" class="action-default scalable action-secondary" >
            Apply
        </button>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <script>
        require(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function($) {
            if ($('#p_method_use_reward_points').prop('checked')) {
                $('.test').show();
                console.log('working');
            }else{
                $('.test').hide();
                console.log('not working');
            }
            $('#submit_reward').on('click', function (e){
                let getPoints = $('#custom_reward_set').val();
                let checkField = $('#custom_reward_set').prop("readonly");
                // alert(getPoints);
                if (!getPoints){
                    alert('PLease add reward points');
                }
                if (getPoints) {
                    $("#custom_reward_set").prop("readonly", !$("#custom_reward_set").attr('readonly'));
                    if ($('#custom_reward_set').is('[readonly]')) {
                        $("#custom_reward_set").css({
                            "background-color": "#EBEBE4",
                            "border": "1px solid #ABADB3", "cursor": "not-allowed"
                        });
                    }else{
                        $('#custom_reward_set').removeAttr('style');
                    }
                }
               e.preventDefault();

            })
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```